# WPF Custom Popup

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, contentcontrol

I have an unique problem with WPF Popups.

In my project I need to get the bitmap of the full screen WPF application and send it out.
For this I use RenderTargetBitmap on my main canvas. Everything is good until I started using Menu & Combobox. Both of them use Popup to display the submenu items. So from what I read Popups are implemented as a separate Window and it is not a child of the MainWindow. So render bitmap will not get the bitmap for it.

So my solution was to implement a custom popup and change the controltemplate for MenuItem.

In my custom popup, IsOpenChanged event I do this

```
        private void PopupPanel_IsOpenChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                ContentControl childControl = new ContentControl();
                childControl.Content = this.Content;

                Canvas rootCanvas = FindAncester<Canvas>(this);
                rootCanvas.Children.Add(childControl);

                childControl.Focus();

                Child = childControl;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Child != null)
                {
                    Canvas rootCanvas = FindAncester<Canvas>(this);
                    rootCanvas.Children.Remove(Child);

                    Child = null;
                 }
            }
        }
```

The idea is to display a child ContentControl on top of my main canvas as a popup.
When I step through everything goes through fine, except that I cannot see anything on the screen.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is far from unique... the fact that `ToolTip`s and `Popup`s don't appear in screenshots is well documented. The general solution is, as you suggest, to simply create a pretend `Popup` control. Now, I can't tell you what's wrong with your example, but I can simply provide you with some XAML that will display a pretend `Popup` control. Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Declare normal view content here -->
    <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="White" BorderBrush="LightGray" 
        BorderThickness="1" Width="200" Height="100" Panel.ZIndex="10">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Direction="270" ShadowDepth="7" 
                Opacity="0.5" />
        </Border.Effect>
        <TextBlock Text="I'm a fake Popup control" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image]

To make this more useful, I'd add a `Binding` for the `TextBlock.Text` property and another for the `Visibility` property, so that you can also control when it appears and disappears.